# 熱画像に対して顔の検出をしたい

Tags: python, 画像, 画像処理

熱画像に対して顔の検出をしたいと考えています。
pythonおよびディープラーニングを用いて、Windows10環境下でやりたいと考えています。
そこで熱画像に対して顔の検出を行うための学習済みモデルを探しているのですが
なかなか見つかりません。どこにあるでしょうか。

---

I want to detect a face on a thermal image.
I want to do it under Windows 10 environment using python and deep learning.
So I'm looking for a trained model for face detection on thermal images.
I can't find it easily. Where is it?

Comment: 個人的に思いつくのは、顔検出のためのデータセットに画像加工をかけて熱画像風にして再学習させるか、既存の学習済みモデルを自前のデータセットで転移学習させることですかね。

Comment: なるほど...結構難しそうですね。

Comment: 顔検出ができるだけで良いのであれば、画像加工についてはある程度ランダムにして、imagemagickなどで何パターンか生成すれば良いと思うので、画像加工で学習させるのが比較的楽にできるのかなという印象はあります。

例えば色情報は捨てて、グレースケールにするという方法もありますし、何ならエッジ検出の結果の方で学習・推論させるという手もあります。

Comment: 色々考えてくださりありがとうございます。実は呼吸の様子を得るために顔だけでなく鼻部分も別に検出したいと考えています。顔が映っている熱画像を集めたデータセットだけならたくさん配布されているので、それをを3000枚ほどダウンロードしたのち、それらすべてにvottというアノテーションツールを用いて顔と鼻の部分を囲ってアノテーションを作成しているっていう感じなのですが、これだとものすごい時間がかかりそうですよね...。再学習なら確かに少ない枚数でもこなせそうな気がするので、とりあえず顔だけでもなんとかやってみます!

Comment: あ、同じ画像を熱画像風に加工する場合はアノテーション作り直す必要ないか。

Comment: VoTTを利用する場合でも、既存のモデルを読み込んで領域とラベルを推論させることも可能なので、ある程度精度があがってくれば半自動的に領域を作成できるのではないかなと思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます!VoTTによるアノテーションも無事終わったので後はなんとかやってみたいと思います